# Function to be executed on home page only

Tags: jquery-mobile, multipage

I have a multi page jquery mobile document.
Structure something like.

Page A

Page B

Page C

I know I can execute function on every pageshow by using pageshow but when u link back to page A say by #PageA in browser it leaves main URL only. So I want to execute a function when user is on mydomain.com

Comment: I do not understand that part: "but when u link back to page A say by #PageA in browser it leaves main URL only. So I want to execute a function when user is on mydomain.com"

Comment: @mvw suppose I got mydomain.com and its default page is PageA. It will show it by default. To move to page b in it we can make it by using #PAGEB and url in location bar will turn to mydomain.com/#pageb. Now if user is coming back to Page A by using on #pageA and in location bar it remain mydomain.com only. Now in this stage I need to execute a function how to dow that??

Answer (score 0):

I can propose general solution. For each page you can have div

```
<div class="page_{variable}"></div>
```

and check by jQuery whether you have

```
    $(".page_A"), $(".page_B")
```

and so on. I hope it helps.